# jQuery not worked on my site. What's wrong?

Tags: jquery

Below is my demo site.
http://122.155.10.35/~bkkvoice/

All jQuery script not work but alert() function.

below is my script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert('Hello, World!!');
  $('.hideMe').hide();
});
```

I use jquery code from google ( https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js )

I think the code is not the problem but can't find what's the problem is.

Need help.

Comment: I get the alert, seems fine to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything works fine, except element with class .hideMe doesn't exist.
Every galery works.

Seems like you are using Mootools at this site.
I can see follow:

```
> console.log(jQuery);
function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)}
> $ == jQuery
false
```

$ - is not a jQuery. Use `jQuery.noConflict()`

Comment: not in Chrome - if you open up javascript debugging you get the error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'hide' of null' - which shouldn't happen even if .hideMe doesn't exist

Comment: if $ is not jquery - it's not a fact that $('.hideMe') will return not null value.

Comment: @InviS I got it. I found that I use MooTools with The Slideshow plugins like you said. Thanks a lot.